# how to implement search box in google earth web?

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Hi i am working on a project with google earth,but in the web view there is no search box to find the location in google earth,can someone please help me how to implement a search box for finding the location in google earth.

I have tried google earth in desktop view,there i find a search option and all but in web version there is no search option.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but what you are looking for is something called Geocoding, converting Addresses into Geographic coordinates. In the GE Plugin you have to implement it yourself.

You will have to use another API for that, and Google has one you can use: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ 
If you are also using the Google Maps API you can use its Geocoding Service:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function doGeocode(address, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': ""+address}, function(results, status) {
        if(status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
            var lat = location.lat();
            var lon = location.lng();
            callback(200, lat, lon);
        }else{
            callback(500);
        }
    });//function geocode
}
```

This is another good Geocoding API: http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/

For either API I believe the examples are pretty straight forward, you just have to grab the Address from the user, then call the API with the value and grab the LatLng from the result, and center the GE camera on that location:

```
// Get the current view.
var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// Set new latitude and longitude values.
lookAt.setLatitude(lat);
lookAt.setLongitude(lng);

// Update the view in Google Earth.
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

Good luck with your project.